# windows phone animation - change opacity of all elements except one child element

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to animate tap on an item in a listbox. On the tap event, I want everything to fade out except the element I tapped i.e. I want the opacity of entire "LayoutRoot" grid to change to 0 from 1, but I want the elementi tapped alone to be visible. Note: There are many many child elements within layout root, so setting the backgroundbrush opacity on the top moist grid does not work on any of the other child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reduce opacity to 0 on tapping for all other elements in the ListBox, leaving only tapped element with original opacity = 1.

Comment: I know this can be done, but it does not scale at all. When I navigate back to the page, I have to iterate and enable the opacity on every item. Also, with the latest LongListSelector in wp8 it is really hard to determine items that are in view